# How to open little popup menu for selecting wifi in android?

Tags: java, android, android-wifi

I noticed this half screen wifi selection menu in some Android Apps.
[image]

I would like to use this menu in my own app, to give the user the possibility to select the wifi without jumping to settings app.
I didn't find any instruction how to do this. However AndroidStudios Layout Inspector showed me that its belonging to the system, not to the app.
Anyone knows how to open this menu ?

Comment: Have you tried any answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called a Settings Panel:

https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/exploring-android-q-settings-panels-d308525b8345

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [`Settings Panel`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Panel)

This is for Android Q.
Here's an example to how to call it.

```
startActivityForResult(Intent(Settings.Panel.ACTION_INTERNET_CONNECTIVITY), INTERNET_SETTINGS_REQUEST)
```